# pattern based replace of string in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

i am trying to replace based on a pattern and i am getting error.

```
{{n.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")}}
```

n is a number.

> Error: [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unexpected next character  at
>   columns 36-36 [] in expression

Comment: Try doing the replace in a scope function and use `ng-bind-html` instead of `{{}}` notation.

Answer (score 0):

angular's probably having a hard time with that regex being inline in the template, you could put that replace statement into a helper function on the scope:

```
$scope.convert = function(val) {
  return val.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
}
```

then in your template call that function:

```
{{ convert(n) }}
```

another option would be to create a custom filter:

```
app.filter('convert', function() {
  return function(input) {
    return input.toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");  
  };
});
```

then pipe your value to that filter:

```
{{ n | convert }}
```